# A more refined Javascript typeof?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Is there a way for typeof to return what an object is?

```
typeof {};
```

returns "object"

```
typeof [];
```

also returns "object". Is there a way in js to return "array"?

On top of that, is there a way to tell if an object is a DOM object, a javascript object or whatever object?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof Since everything is an object you have to play games to get further details.

Comment: See [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

`[] instanceof Array` is `true`
`({}) instanceof Array` is `false`

This also applies to non-Array types.

`document.body instanceof `[`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) is `true`

Comment: If you really need to write code that checks whether a variable is a DOM element or a JavaScript object, you should probably ask why you're getting both in the same function in the first place.

Comment: as @arcyqwerty mentioned, you can do it like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gmjy3ybv/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't extend the `typeof` operator but for better type inspection you can (ab)use [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([]) === '[object Array]'
Object.prototype.toString.call(document) === '[object HTMLDocument]`
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient solution. You should use [the `instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Comment: `instanceof` does not *return what an object is* so this is the only answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) for it.

> The `Array.isArray()` method returns true if an object is an array, false if it is not.

Comment: It does not *return what an object is*